# firebase web - Google Authentication domain not authorized

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, dns, firebase-authentication

I've been having an issue on Google authentication in Firebase saying this:

> This domain (example.com) is not authorized to run this operation. Add it to the OAuth redirect domains list in the Firebase console -> Auth section -> Sign in method tab.

It makes no sense because I definitely added it to the list of authorized domains in the Firebase console auth section.

[image: Firebase Auth section]

Am I missing something?

Comment: you might need to add the exact url and not just the domain ?

Comment: @kigiri what do you mean to add the exact url? I even included the subdomain if that makes sense it's `xxx.xxxxx.app`

Comment: Check you are using the right API key for that project. I have seen situations where 2 projects are used and the API for a different project (where the domain is not whitelisted) is provided.